# Reduce memory consumption in Firefox with multiple large JSON files coming in through XHR

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am showing a map of the United States using Leaflet.js, where if the user clicks on a state, the map zooms in to view all of the state's census tracts.

The code loads the census tract GeoJSONs (161.3 MB) using 51 XMLHttp requests in a WebWorker, as well as the states GeoJSON (523 KB) using 1 XMLHttp request in the main thread.

There is a significant delay when the page first loads, which (EDIT) is fine with me, because it is unavoidable given the approach I am using, and depends on the user's internet connection. However, in Firefox only (and not Chrome or Safari) there are memory issues. Every time I refresh the page, the memory in the browser builds up, until the browser freezes. The tab's memory alone seems fine, because when I go to `about:performance` (Firefox's Task Manager), and watch the page reload, the memory seems the same every time. But in Mac's Activity Monitor, I can see the memory increasing with every reload.

I have tried deleting variables explicitly in my code, but can't figure out what is happening here. Can we fix this with Firefox?

Full HTML, SSCCE:

```html
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

    <!-- my code -->
    <script src="test_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Full JS, SSCCE:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    /*------------------------------------------------
    -------------- Initialize variables --------------
    ------------------------------------------------*/

    var mapboxAccessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnJpZW5uYWtoIiwiYSI6ImNqbXRsNjN0aTAxZXAzbG13bmh0dGFjNm0ifQ.98TAXgq4Rg1LpM2Oq1rlWw';


    function reqListener() {
        statesData = JSON.parse(this.response);
    }

    // Get main data
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://briennakh.me/accessibility-maps/data/us_states_edited.json?v=' + new Date().getTime()
    xhr.addEventListener('load', reqListener);
    xhr.open('GET', url, false);
    xhr.send();

    /*------------------------------------------------
    -------------- Create map ------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------*/

    // Create basemap 
    var basemap = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
        attribution: '',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        maxZoom: 18,
        accessToken: mapboxAccessToken,
    });

    // Create map 
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: new L.LatLng(37.8, -96),
        zoom: 4,
        layers: [basemap],
    });

    var stateLayer = L.geoJson(statesData, {
        style: stateStyle,
        onEachFeature: onEachState
    }).addTo(map);

    var censusTractLayers = {};

        if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        w = new Worker('worker.js'); // to test worker, must serve on localhost, otherwise Security Error

        // Respond to message sent back from worker
        w.onmessage = function(e) {
            var state = e.data;
            console.log('Received message from worker for ' + state.name)
            censusTractLayers[state.name] = L.geoJson(state, {
                style: tractStyle,
                onEachFeature: onEachTract
            });
        }
    } else {
        // will need to inform user they need an updated browser
        console.log('No support for web worker.');
    } 

    // Load each state's census tracts in the background
    w.postMessage(statesData.features);

    /*------------------------------------------------
    -------------- Define styles ---------------------
    ------------------------------------------------*/
    function tractStyle(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: 'grey',
            weight: .5, // no border
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '1',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        }
    }

    function stateStyle(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: 'grey',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------
    -------------- Define event handlers -------------
    ------------------------------------------------*/
    function onEachState(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: function(e) {
                highlightFeature(e);
            },
            mouseout: function(e) {
                var feature = e.target;
                stateLayer.resetStyle(feature);
            },
            click: function(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());

                // Add census tract layer to map if it has already been loaded
                if (feature.properties.name in censusTractLayers) {
                    censusTractLayers[feature.properties.name].addTo(map);
                } else {
                    console.log('Not loaded yet');  
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function onEachTract(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: function(e) {
                highlightFeature(e);
            },
            mouseout: function(e) {
                var feature = e.target;

                for (i in censusTractLayers) {
                    if(censusTractLayers[i].hasLayer(feature)) {
                        censusTractLayers[i].resetStyle(feature);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var feature = e.target;

        feature.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
            feature.bringToFront(); // to prevent feature overlaps  
        }
    }
}
```

JS for web worker:

```
function reqListener() {
    postMessage(this.response);
}

onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from main script.');

    for (var i in e.data) {
        state = e.data[i].properties.name;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'http://briennakh.me/accessibility-maps/data/census tracts/geojsons/' + state + '.json?v=' + new Date().getTime();
        xhr.addEventListener('load', reqListener);
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Every time I refresh the page`  Is this when you refresh, as in a proper refresh, or refreshing as in re-loading the data?.  If it's refreshing, aka. clicking the refresh button of the browser, then this would an issue with firefox, as a page refresh should clean up everything it left behind.

Comment: `xhr.open('GET', url);`, interestingly seen as your using a webworker, passing `false` as the third parameter make sense here.. `xhr.open('GET', url, fase);`  Currently your loading `async` inside your webworker and that kind of doesn't make much sense, or at least it doesn't if your not limiting / controlling the `async` overlap your going to get with all your requests going off at the same time.. :)

Comment: Oh, and another thing.  Sorry for the multiple comments :).   Using a webworker here to load your data is really not gaining you anything,.  Using `fetch` / `ajax` both in `async` mode would have been just as good if not better.  You would save on IPC / message overhead..

Comment: @Keith The time is lost when the worker messages the data to the main page. If they could send the data in chunks, a worker would be a good solution.

Comment: @Keith yes every time I click the refresh button. I should try on a different computer. Perhaps it's my copy of Firefox. If anyone tries it and has the same problem, please let me know. I don't want the user to have this problem.

Comment: @Teemu   Sorry, what?..  You can get the data in chunks, with or without a webworker.  I'm struggling to see how a webworker here is going to help with anything.   If the OP was doing some sort of pre-processing of the data, I could understand but she is just passing onto the parent.  Maybe I'm missing something here..

Comment: @Keith I originally used a webworker because I was hoping that it would cut down on the lag that the requests generate, especially with massive JSON parsing, by moving this to the background.

Comment: @briennakh  Could you try with passing `false` to your `xhr.open(`,  it shouldn't slow things down, unless you have some sort of cluster server system going.  And in fact might even make things faster, have multiple XHR requests going to the same server at the same time might even cause things to go slower.

Comment: That does help on Chrome and Safari! Mostly gets rid of the lag time on load :) However, it doesn't even make a difference on Firefox (74.0).

Comment: Personally I would try and take the webworker out of the equation.  Remember when you use Postmessage the browser is going to have to serialize/deserialize the data anyway, and this will place massive traffic in the IPC queue.  You have maybe stumbled upon a bug/quirk of firefox and webworkers / IPC.  So avoiding it might be a good solution, and I personally believe it's not gaining you anything anyway.  The only gotcha of course of not using a webworker, you will need to make sure you DO use async, in other words don't pass `false`..